# issues with j2me polish in netbeans

Tags: java, php, netbeans, java-me, j2mepolish

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at de.enough.polish.netbeans.J2mePolishProjectGenerator.generateProjectFromTemplate(J2mePolishProjectGenerator.java:141)
at de.enough.polish.netbeans.J2mePolishProjectTemplateWizardIterator.instantiate(J2mePolishProjectTemplateWizardIterator.java:82)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1046)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:605)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:439)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:248)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:160)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1590)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1531)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2200(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
```

[catch] at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2171)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2229)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$11.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1454)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.lazyValidate(WizardDescriptor.java:1499)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$1900(WizardDescriptor.java:90)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener.actionPerformed(WizardDescriptor.java:2236)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$ProxyListener.invoke(WeakListenerImpl.java:458)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:154)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:219)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1082)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.superShow(NbPresenter.java:1076)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.doShow(NbPresenter.java:1126)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:1098)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.run(NbPresenter.java:128)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:273)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.NbPresenter.show(NbPresenter.java:1083)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1651)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1603)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.showDialog(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:260)
    at org.netbeans.core.windows.services.DialogDisplayerImpl$1AWTQuery.run(DialogDisplayerImpl.java:186)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

What am i supposed to do now?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` this means your array is empty but you still try to access to element at index 0. The stacktrace by itself won't help us to provide you a direct answer. Please post the relevant code that generates this error.

Comment: Can't you provide some of your code, so that we can understand what actually you are doing..